# MiKTeX cannot retrieve attributes for the file...(file name with & and spaces)

Tags: miktex, paths

I ran into a problem when compiling a project this day. The project is working fine when I compile it on my regular hard drive. I also made a copy on a NAS drive, for backup reasons. For working on the projects and compiling I use VSC and its Latexworkshop plugin.

My problem arises when I want to compile the files on the NAS. When doing this, I receive the error
"MiKTeX cannot retrieve attributes for the file..." followed by the path. The path contains "&" and spaces. I already found some hint online, that changing the "args" property in the recipes from "DOC" to "DOCFILE" may enable Latexworkshop to compile such paths. This solved some previous error I had (I forgot this). But for now, I am running out of ideas what might be happening here.

Thanks for help in advance and best regards!

Log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.11) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.11.2)  9 JAN 2021 20:20
entering extended mode
**"//s4d-fs.d.ethz.ch/itet-home$/tewald/Documents/LaTeX/Ausschreibungen/Optimization in Matlab/SAMA - 2020HS - Thomas Ewald - Optimization in Matlab.tex"
("//s4d-fs.d.ethz.ch/itet-home$/tewald/Documents/LaTeX/Ausschreibungen/Optimization in Matlab/SAMA - 2020HS - Thomas Ewald - Optimization in Matlab.tex"
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count175
\c@section=\count176
\c@subsection=\count177
\c@subsubsection=\count178
\c@paragraph=\count179
\c@subparagraph=\count180
\c@figure=\count181
\c@table=\count182
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) ("//s4d-fs.d.ethz.ch/itet-home$/tewald/Documents/LaTeX/Ausschreibungen/Optimization in Matlab\ThesesFlyerStyle.sty" ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2020/10/27 3.51 The Babel package
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2020/10/27 3.51 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count183
\U@D=\dimen139
\l@babelnohyphens=\language84
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def")
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count184

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-german\ngerman.ldf"
Language: ngerman 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (post-1996 orthography)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-german\ngermanb.ldf"
Language: ngermanb 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (post-1996 orthography)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 121.
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf"
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: \l@canadian = using hyphenrules for english
(babel)             (\language0) on input line 102.
Package babel Info: \l@australian = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language78) on input line 105.
Package babel Info: \l@newzealand = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language78) on input line 108.
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\lmodern.sty"
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX
 (C:\miktex\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
) (C:\miktex\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 (C:\miktex\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
) (C:\miktex\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
) (C:\miktex\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (C:\miktex\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (C:\miktex\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (C:\miktex\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (C:\miktex\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (C:\miktex\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen140
\Hy@linkcounter=\count185
\Hy@pagecounter=\count186
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (C:\miktex\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
) (C:\miktex\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count187
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4338.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def"
File: puenc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4464.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4469.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4472.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4479.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4484.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4717.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count188
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5076.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen141
 (C:\miktex\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
 (C:\miktex\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count189
\Field@Width=\dimen142
\Fld@charsize=\dimen143
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6352.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6355.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6367.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6372.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6377.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6417.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6421.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty"
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi package
with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count190
\c@Item=\count191
\c@Hfootnote=\count192
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty"
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery package
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count193
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count194
 (C:\miktex\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 (C:\miktex\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 286.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip49
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count195
\Gm@cntv=\count196
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count197
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen144
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen145
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen146
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen147
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen148
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen149
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen150
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen151
\Gm@dimlist=\toks18
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty"
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrextend.sty"
Package: scrextend 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (extend other classes with features of KOMA-Script classes)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrkbase.sty"
Package: scrkbase 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbase.sty"
Package: scrbase 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile.sty"
Package: scrlfile 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile-hook.sty"
Package: scrlfile-hook 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeFile with sig. 'm' on line 61.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterFile with sig. 'm' on line 65.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeClass with sig. 'm' on line 69.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforePackage with sig. 'm' on line 73.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterAtEndOfClass with sig. 'smo+m' on line 83.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterAtEndOfPackage with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     93.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \scrlfile@AfterClass with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     173.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterClass with sig. '' on line 174.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \scrlfile@AfterPackage with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     191.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterPackage with sig. '' on line 192.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplaceInput with sig. '' on line 193.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplaceClass with sig. 'mm' on line 196.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplacePackage with sig. 'mm' on line 199.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplaceInput with sig. '' on line 200.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplaceClass with sig. 'm' on line 203.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplacePackage with sig. 'mm' on line 206.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \PreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 's+om' on
(LaTeX3)     line 234.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \StorePreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 'm' on
(LaTeX3)     line 242.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ResetPreventPackageFromLoading with sig. '' on
(LaTeX3)     line 247.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnPreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 'sm' on
(LaTeX3)     line 261.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeClosingMainAux with sig. 'om' on line
(LaTeX3)     274.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterReadingMainAux with sig. 'om' on line 287.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \protected@immediate@write with sig. 'm+m+m' on
(LaTeX3)     line 298.

 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlogo.sty"
Package: scrlogo 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))))

LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotemark  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.
```

Alternatively, here is a link to the log file.

https://polybox.ethz.ch/index.php/s/l7686cpxakHgJy7

Comment: How can I attach the .log file to this post?

Comment: just copy the contents of the log into your question with three `\`\`\`` on the line above and the line below to mark it as a code block

Comment: Hey, thanks! To this point I posted a big chunk of it, but unfortunately it has sth like 35000 chars, where here I am only allowed to post 30000.

Comment: wow you don't want to make it easy for the system:-) `//s4d-fs.d.ethz.ch/itet-home$/tewald/Documents/LaTeX/Ausschreibungen/Optimization in Matlab/SAMA - 2020HS - Thomas Ewald - Optimization in Matlab.tex"` it seems you are really passing that full path tolatex rather than doing the normal thing of cd to that folder then `pdflatex "SAMA - 2020HS - Thomas Ewald - Optimization in Matlab.tex"` (although even that filename seems brave.

Comment: You might do better if you map `//s4d-fs.d.ethz.ch/itet-home$` to a drive letter sat `t:` so you can use `t:/tewald/Documents/LaTeX/...` but I don't know I'm not a mikktex user , sorry

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers! To the path: I think my main problem would be the //s4d-fs.d.ethz.ch/itet-home$/... part. I have the same files just on a local drive, where the rest of the path is the same, and this works fine. So I will try the hint of David Carlisle

Comment: It seems that mapping in a way works - I can compile a simple document there. Copying the complete folder structure to the new directory and trying to compile still throws errors, but building the document new from scratch may be possible...

Comment: I don't know why, but somehow I have to build all my main files new from scratch because this error keeps popping up, no matter if I mapped the directory path or not. But when I do it, it works. The files I \input I don't have to write again.
Deleting temporary and auxiliary files does not solve this issue, only setting up a new main file completely.
This topic can be closed, I can work with the "solution".